# How to add two sidebars in wordpress twentyeleven theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am newbie to the WordPress. I want to make `two sidebars`. One in the `left` and another in the `right hand side`. I want to use `twenty-eleven` theme and then `customise` that. So any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Sidebar at the left is not very likely, i would not really recommend it. But take at look at this to get you started ..http://wordpress.org/support/topic/twentyten-how-to-switch-right-sidebar-to-left

Comment: @JonathanRomer thyanks for the reply but I want two sidebars in both sides of the post not to move the right sidebar to the left hand side.

Answer (score 2):

Very Simple and easy way, first make a design with two sidebar, one on left and one on right, then call specific widgets on right and left side bar.

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar (''WIDGET AREA NAME); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was just going through this question which is little bit similar with my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727269/adding-two-sidebars-in-wordpress-child-theme
So can you tell me how to solve the hard code part which has been asked in that question?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in Index.php or home page

```
<div class="sidebar_left" id="sidebar_left">

<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-left' ) ) : ?>
        <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-left' ); ?>
        </div><!-- #secondary -->
    <?php endif; ?>


</div>
```

and CSS for this is here

```
#sidebar_left{
    float:left;
    /*width: 303px;*/
    border: 2px solid #A2A2A2;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    margin: -532px 0 -62px -123px
    padding: 0;
    top: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should :

- create a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) of twenty-eleven
- and add a widget area using [`register_sidebar`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar)

You will find a lot of tutorials for doing this, e.g. [this one](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/11/08/sidebars-in-wordpress).